# Error parsing parameter 'paths': Unable to retrieve <bucket-url> received non 200 status code of 403 aws S3 IAM

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

My goal is to make a policy in aws IAM that allows full access to only ONE PARTICULAR S3 bucket, I will then attach that policy to one user to test it out, after which that policy will be attached to an IAM role which will be given to my EC2 instance.
The problem is I'm encountering error after I try to access my bucket through aws cli with the user credentials.
The error given is :

> Error parsing parameter 'paths': Unable to retrieve 
>   received non 200 status code of 403.

My policy is:

```
{
    "Version": "<version-number>",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:*:<account-id>:job/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name>",
                "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name>/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I had first enabled the "Block all public access" in my bucket but later on I set it to false.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What CLI command you execute when you get error?

Comment: guess I should add this to origin question as well but the command I'm executing is:
aws s3 ls <bucket-url>

Comment: You don't need to provide bucket-url, it should be only bucket name `aws s3 ls <bucketname>`

Comment: Thank you so much that solved the problem.  Now I feel stupid. :p